# Javascript declare multiple variables with the same values

Tags: javascript

Maybe I should use some kind of loop or something. But I don't have any idea how to declare this, excluding do it manually.

Is there any solution that will have only a few lines for all of this. Because, there should be 100 variable, despite I only presented 5, I didn't want to type all night.

```
a1=1; a2=1; a3=1; a4=1; a5=1;

function myfn1() {
a1++;
//unique function code
}
function myfn2() {
a2++;
//unique function code
}
function myfn3() {
a3++;
//unique function code
}
function myfn4() {
a4++;
//unique function code
}
function myfn5() {
a5++;
//unique function code
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using an array?

Comment: The reason is I don't know how to declare a fn with an array :(

Comment: I recommend to read a [tutorial about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Comment: So you have 100 unique functions? Is it safe to assume that they're actually the same, except for the variable they use? If so, you can eliminate all that repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't answering your question, I think this approach will help you more in the long run (and probably in the short run too). Check out using an array, which is just a collection of data. Check out the following code.

```
var arr = [];
for(var i =0; i <= 100; i++){
  arr[i] = i;
}
```

this gives you a collection like this [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100] that you can then manipulate, etc etc.

*edit or if you want them all to have the same value, then

```
var arr = [];
for(var i =0; i <= 100; i++){
  arr[i] = 1;
}
```